# RestTemplate Customization: Configure your custom instance with a RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When researching how to customize Spring's `RestTemplate`, I came across the **4.15.1. RestTemplate Customization** section of the official Spring Boot docs (see excerpt and link at the bottom of this question).

It says "make sure to configure your custom instance with a `RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer`". I searched for "`RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer`" but found nothing, so apparently this is something that I need to implement.

Just looking at the signature, and comparing to `RestTemplateBuilder#configure` ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.html#configure-T-)), it seems like the idea is that `configurer.configure` takes a `RestTemplateBuilder` and merges the configuration with Spring Boot's default `RestTemplateBuilder` configuration.

I could write a bunch of imperative code to do this configuration merging, but I suspect that I'm missing something here and there's a much easier way to do this with some out-of-the-box Spring features.

So, how can I implement a `RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer`? Or did I misunderstand the docs?

**4.15.1. RestTemplate Customization ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-resttemplate-customization))**

> Finally, you can also create your own RestTemplateBuilder bean. To
> prevent switching off the auto-configuration of a RestTemplateBuilder
> and prevent any RestTemplateCustomizer beans from being used, make
> sure to configure your custom instance with a
> RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer. The following example exposes a
> RestTemplateBuilder with what Spring Boot would auto-configure, except
> that custom connect and read timeouts are also specified:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder(RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer configurer) {
    return configurer.configure(new RestTemplateBuilder()).setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
}
```

Comment: `RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer` was introduced in Spring Boot 2.4.0. What version of Spring Boot are you using? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/client/RestTemplateBuilderConfigurer.html

Comment: Thanks Scott, that would definitely be why I couldn't find it!